# Updating connected entities with one-to-many relationships in entity framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a one-to-many relationship that am trying to update but get the error

Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

**UPDATED**

***The update method will work for as long as the beneficiaries collection is not being changed or updated.***

The code looks like

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Beneficiary> _beneficiaries;
    public IEnumerable<Beneficiary> Beneficiaries => _beneficiaries;

    public void AddBeneficiary(string name)
    {
        var beneficiary = new Beneficiary(Id, name);
        _beneficiaries.Add(beneficiary);
    }
}

public sealed class Beneficiary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Beneficiary(int employeeId, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        EmployeeId = employeeId;
    }
}

//Extracted from repo method
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity != null)
        _dbSet.Update(entity);
}

// Extracted Actual update from application service
if (incomingEmployee.Beneficiaries.Any())
{
    if (employeeFromStore.Beneficiaries.Any())
    {
        employeeFromStore.Beneficiaries.ToList()
            .ForEach(existingBeneficiary => 
        employeeFromStore.RemoveBeneficiary(existingBeneficiary)); //Method skipped for brevity

        //Tried calling this too
        //_employeeRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    incomingEmployee.Beneficiaries.ToList().ForEach(beneficiary =>
    {
        employeeFromStore.AddBeneficiary(beneficiary.Name);
    });
}

_employeeRepository.Update(employeeFromStore);
_employeeRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

I feel the issue is in how the tracker treats the update for navigation properties collection but I could be wrong.

I have also attempted to use the change tracker for updates with a method like below

```
public void ApplyCurrentValues<TEntity>(TEntity original, TEntity current)
        where TEntity : class
{
    //if it is not attached, attach original and set current values
    base.Entry<TEntity>(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(current);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made headway after reading about how update works. Basically as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-2.1)
, and this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10174). When Update method is invoked the state of the whole entity including all reachable entities through navigation properties is marked as modified.
If you are trying to add beneficiaries to an existing employee, the SaveChanges() throws since it expects to modify a record(s) with the primary key(s) provided but finds none in the database. Update method seemed not the best candidate.

I opted to make the Update method from the repository base overridable in the EmployeeRepository as below

```
//Update method in the repository base
//Made method virtual to enable overriding
public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity != null)
        _dbSet.Update(entity);
}

//Update method from EmployeeRepository
public override void Update(Employee employee)
{
    var employeeFromStore = _unitOfWork.Employees.Where(p => p.Id == employee.Id)
        .Include(p => p.Beneficiaries)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (employeeFromStore != null)
    {
        context.Entry(employeeFromStore).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);

        //Replacing the whole collection
        foreach (var beneficiary in employeeFromStore.Beneficiaries)
        {
            if (employee.Beneficiaries.Any())
                context.Entry(beneficiary).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }

        //Adding new collection
        foreach (var beneficiaryToAdd in employee.Beneficiaries)
        {
            var newBeneficiary = new Beneficiary(beneficiaryToAdd.EmployeeId, beneficiaryToAdd.Name);

            employeeFromStore.AddBeneficiary(newBeneficiary.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this answer can be improved or tweaked to suit specific situations. For instance, other than clearing the persisted collection, one can opt for an update